# No display result in TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner, I did a simple task but I do not see the result in TextView. How can I solve my problem?

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
EditText editText1, editText2;
TextView textView;

public void Add(View v)
{
    float x = Float.parseFloat(editText1.getText().toString());
    float y = Float.parseFloat(editText2.getText().toString());
    float sum = x + y;

    textView.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
   }
}
```

The second option I tried was:

```
textView.setText("SUM = " + String.valueOf(sum));
```

But then I receive a message:
Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders.

PS. Of course i added method android:onClick = "Add"

Comment: You have not called Add(View v) method anywehere

Comment: kindly add your xml

Answer (score 0):

You can try **sum.toString()**  instead of String.valueOf(sum)

Answer (score 0):

you better make button onclick in java, then display the string value to the textview

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    handleButtonClick();
}

private void handleButtonClick() {
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          addAndSetResult();
      }
  });
}

private void addAndSetResult() {
   // inside here do the add logic and set result to textview
   EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
   float x = Float.parseFloat(editText1.getText().toString());
   float y = Float.parseFloat(editText2.getText().toString());
   float sum = x + y;
   String sumStr = String.valueOf(sum);

   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
   textView.setText(sumStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do your work

```
 textView.setText(Float.toString(sum))
```